# Replacing and renaming a file throughout a git history

Tags: git

I have a file in a git repository that is too large to push to GitHub.  However, zipping the file brings it well under their threshold.

Given this, what I would like to do is modify the history to completely replace the file with the zipped version (including renaming it).

For example:

```
file.txt
```

Should turn into:

```
file.zip (or file.txt.zip)
```

With it's contents replaced throughout history accordingly.

Most of the information I can find about changing history focuses on removing files or replacing text.  I haven't been able to find anything regarding entirely replacing a file.

It's also worth noting that the changes aren't shared at this point (so I shouldn't break anyone else's repo) and the file is not referenced directly elsewhere in the project (so it shouldn't render any prior commits invalid).

This seems like something that should be doable with `git filter-branch` though I'm not yet sure how (and am a little hesitant to just start trying things).  What's the best way to accomplish this change?

Comment: It is doable, but not advised if you're sharing the code with others...

Comment: Does the file change throughout the history of the project? Then zipping it removes the ability to inspect changes between versions. Otherwise, if it's a static file, it is questionable whether it belongs in the repository at all.

Comment: @mkrieger1 At least at this point it I don't believe there are any changes. And your point is certainly valid, re-hosting the data to elsewhere could be a potential option.  That said, while the data is mostly static, it may change in the future and it's possible that some of the code may or may not need to change, so having it with the code history has it's advantages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before anything please be **sure** that thoses commits are local only, and are not shared with anyone. Otherwise, avoid rewritting history!

If you feel safe....

Get the hash of the commit where `file.txt` was introduced (let's say, *foo*). Then:

```
git rebase -i <foo>~1
```

you should locate the *foo* line and replace "pickup" with "edit". Save and quit, the [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) will trigger. Then:

```
git mv file.txt file.zip
# do modification to file.zip (eg. erase it with the real zip)
git add file.zip
git rebase --continue
```

This should do the trick without having to make other branches or cherry-picks!

Comment: This is definitely one of those solutions where it seems so obvious after seeing it.  Worked perfectly and was a nice reminder of the power of interactive rebasing.

Comment: What if the file to be replaced is in the initial commit (so that <foo>~1 is not defined)?